# Workflows doesn't appear under the custom list and doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-list

I created new custom list and list workflows as follow steps.

-First, I created custom list.

Then I want to add new workflows to this list and i clicked New.

[image]

Then I'm creating new workflows with email action.

[image]
[image]

and I'm checking the workflows properties as follow image.
[image]

Finally I'm saving and publishing this workflow. But when I add new item this custom list, mail doesn't come. And when I look my custom lists workflows, it seems to be empty.
How can I solve this? When I'm creating new workflow I'm checking this custom list and I'm saving changes but my workflows doesn't appear under the custom list. Where am I do mistake?

Please help me. Thank for advice.

[image]

Comment: The workflow is likely not associated with the list.  You can confirm what workflows are associated with a list by going to the list in your browser, selecting 'List' from the ribbon followed by 'Workflow Settings'

Comment: @Dovahkiin thanks for advice but when I'm selecting Workflow Settings in browser then I'm selecting a workflow this list but I'm getting this message "This workflow cannot be customized from the browser. Use a sharepoint-compatible workflow editing tool, such as Microsoft Sharepoint Designer, to edit this workflow." I'm not want to edit this workflows. I  want to associated with the list. How can I do this from browser?

Comment: In Workflow settings there is a link to Add a workflow  http://imgur.com/eucXHCE.  If you don't see your workflow there it probably wasn't created successfully.  Here is a pretty good tutorial on workflows http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/419037/Create-Workflow-using-SharePoint-Designer

Comment: @Dovahkiin I'm thinking I created workflows succesfully and when I'm selecting Workflow settings I see my workflows this list. But when I want to selecting those workflows, I got above warning, because I created those workflows via Sharepoint Designer. And I tried Add Workflow as your advice but it didn't associate my custom list.